# Unable redefine gutter width in Susy

Tags: css, sass, susy-sass, susy

SOLVED!!
(see bottom)

Obviously I'm new to Susy. Read all the documentation. I've read the free chapters of Zell's tutorial and read most of his blog posts. Looked through other sources haphazardly. Nowhere have I found information that touches on modifying gutter-width.

I've been trying to change the gutter width on my primary grid and the changes show no response whatsoever. I've tried all the measurement units I've seen. Still, nothing happnens!

here's the code:

```
#grid{
      @include container(4);
      gutter-width: 5%;
      }
```

I also tried:

```
 #grid{
      @include container(4);
      gutter-width: 2px;
      }
```

and

```
 #grid{
      @include container(4);
      gutter-width: 400px;
      }
```

and

```
 #grid{
      @include container(4);
      gutter-width: 1/6;
      }
```

and

```
 #grid{
      @include container(4);
      gutter-width: 0;
      }
```

and

```
 #grid{
      @include container(4);
      gutter-width: 1.6em;
      }
```

You get the picture. I also tried removing the `width` suffix and iterating value variations ad-infinitum.

```
 #grid{
      @include container(4);
      gutter: 2px;
      }
```

Nothing.
Nathan.
Nada.

What gives?

*EDIT*

Here's the CSS pertaining to the container grid, `#grid`

```
#grid {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-image:   url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'), url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 50%, 100% 50%, color-stop(0%, rgba(102, 102, 255, 0.25)), color-stop(80%, rgba(179, 179, 255, 0.25)), color-stop(80%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))), -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 1, color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(102, 102, 255, 0.25), rgba(179, 179, 255, 0.25) 80%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%), -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 1px);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(102, 102, 255, 0.25), rgba(179, 179, 255, 0.25) 80%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 1px);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(102, 102, 255, 0.25), rgba(179, 179, 255, 0.25) 80%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%), linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 1px);
  background-size: 26.31579%, 100% 24px;
  background-origin: content-box, border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
  background-position: left top;
  gutter-width: 5%;
}

#grid:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
   }
```

SOLVED

The problem was that I wrote "gutter" and not "gutter

Comment: Did you look at the compiled CSS?

Comment: No, but I will. What should I be looking for?

Comment: well if i had any idea how to find it in the CSS markup then I would've done that.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the markup that is generated through susy. I asked for your help on where that might be found in the CSS. 

This is unique content relating to this technology, therefore useful and of value. 

I ask that you stay on topic.